# constraints for indirect dependency in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, dependency-management

How do I specify version constraints of indirect dependencies in `setup.py`?

###### Assumptions

- My python package `p` depends on package `x`
- `x` depends on package `y` but my package `p` does not directly depend on `y`.
- Correspondingly, I have sth like `x>=1.2.3` in the `install_requires` in `setup.py`but do not have `Y` in `install_requires`.
- but some `x` functionality I need in `p` fails if `y` is outside some version range.

###### Alternative approaches and the question

If it were about installation using `requirements.txt` I would just add sth like `y>=2.3.4,<=3.4.5` to a file `constraints.txt` and install using `pip install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt`. But I want to have `setup.py` to make it more easily distributable.

So how do I achieve the same effect in `setup.py`?

###### Why not just put the `y` version constraints in `setup.py`?

Directly specifying the `y` version range in `install_requires` in `setup.py` works. But the downside is that it forces installation of `y` even if `x` were to drop the `y` dependency at some point. That's the reason I would still want to have a solution closer to the `constraints.txt` file approach.

Comment: If `x` depend on `y` then when installing `x`, `y` will be installed so there is normally no problem

Comment: yes, `y` will be installed but,  unless I somehow provide version constraints for `y`,  it will not install a working combination of `x` and `y` .  so the question is how to guide setup.py to install the correct version _without_ directly requiring `y`

Comment: I assume that the best way to fix it would be inside setup.py  of `x`. but in my case `x` is a bigger 3rd party project where I cannot hope for them to change it. so I need to work around it

Comment: It might be complicated, I can only see as a solution to specify a precise version of `y` and hope that it meets the requirements of `x`.

Comment: hmm, yes. specifying the `y` version range in `install_requires` as well seems the best option. the only downside I see is that it forces installation of `y` even if `x` were to drop the `y` dependency at some point. that's the reason I would still want to have a solution closer to the `constraints.txt` file approach  (edited my question with this context info)

Comment: It sounds like `x` is broken. Can't you just open a ticket explaining your issue to the `x` team and have it fixed upstream? Optionnally, fix it yourself, and submit it to them, and eventually use your fork in the mean time.

Comment: @Keldorn you're right that this is sth that should ideally be fixed upstream in `x`. The problem in this particular case is that it's an issue for an older version of `x` (which I need for other compatibility reasons) and does not happen on newer versions. So, they would have to update an outdated version of `x` which does not seem reasonable.

Comment: Summing the discussion so far up, it seems that my best option is indeed to just explicitly add the `y` version constraints in my own `setup.py` -- even though `y` is not a direct dependency of my project