# How to impose constraints on sub-dependencies in setuptools?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools

#### Background

Suppose my package depends on the `foo` package, and `foo`, in turn, depends on the `bar` package, specifically `bar>=1.0.0`.

In other words, `bar` is a sub-dependency for my package.

Following [best practice](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/), my `pyproject.toml` (or `setup.cfg`) specifies only ***direct*** dependencies, ***no*** sub-dependencies. For example:

```ini
[project]
# ...
dependencies = [
    "foo>=2.0",
]
```

#### Problem

Now suppose `bar` version `1.0.1` has been released in order to patch a security vulnerability, but `foo` has not picked up on this yet (it still uses `bar>=1.0.0`).

Instead of waiting for `foo` to catch up, I want to make sure my package enforces the use of `bar>=1.0.1`.

#### Current solution

The obvious solution would be to add a constraint to my `pyproject.toml` as follows:

```ini
[project]
# ...
dependencies = [
    "foo>=2.0",
    # constraint for sub-dependency
    "bar>=1.0.1",
]
```

This works, but now it looks like my project depends directly on `bar`, whereas `bar` is only a sub-dependency: I don't import anything directly from `bar`, and if `foo` ever decides not to use `bar` anymore, I won't need it either.

#### Question

Is there a better way to specify a constraint for a sub-dependency using [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html)?

Comment: Just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72461443), which is almost an exact duplicate of mine. Unfortunately, it is unanswered.

Comment: From my point of view, if your project is a library then it is not your responsibility to put version constraints on indirect dependencies. If your project is an application then things are different (I would say that maybe you should consider excluding the faulty versions of indirect dependencies).

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks. I do like to patch any known holes as quickly as possible. :-)

Comment: In the end, the responsibility always falls on the application's maintainers to choose the right combination of dependency versions. Library maintainers should only declare known incompatibilities. And one could argue that security holes are not incompatibilities, so as a library maintainer I am not even sure I would exclude a dependency version because it has a potential security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something: no. Not using `setuptools`.

Your package is going to be built into a binary distribution (*wheel*, a `.whl` file). After that point, `setuptools` is no longer in the picture, and the package metadata needs to follow [Core metadata specifications](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/), which do not have any facility for specifying constraints.

`pip` has a relevant option for this:

```
  -c, --constraint <file>     Constrain versions using the given constraints
                              file. This option can be used multiple times.
```

You can read more about constrain files [in pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files).

---

There's also an argument to be made about what counts as a dependency for a package. If people depend on `X` to be secure, and `X` depends (transitively) on `Y` to be secure, then you could argue in a hand-wavy way that this *has to* be taken into account inside the dependencies list, even though there's no coupling in the code.

The counterpoint is that this exposes packages that depend on both `X` and `Y` to a dependency hell. Further, there's no safety hatch in case `Y` stops being necessary for your direct dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. You make a good point (and counterpoint). The constraints file is also an interesting solution when installing from source, but it would be great if something similar were available in `setuptools`, e.g. in the form of a `constraints` section in `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: @djvg You can always pitch your idea in the [Packaging section on Python Discuss](https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/). It seems like a valid usecase, but I'm not sure if this fits current philosophy of metadata specs. It would have to be added to Wheel Metadata specification first.

Comment: See [Python Discuss 21897](https://discuss.python.org/t/dependency-constraints-for-setuptools/21897).